# htaccess not redirecting https to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I am trying to redirect my site to a specific folder using htaccess.

I need **http**://wwww.example.com (http request ) to be redirected to **https**://wwww.example.com/**wp** (change to https and to sub folder wp)

I also need **https**://www.example.com (https request) to be redirected to **https**://www.example.com/**wp** (only redirecting to wp since the original request is already https)

The second example above doesn’t work. When I enter **https**://www.example.com I am not redirected to the /wp.

Here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/wp/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Any idea why the https request is not being redirected?
I would also like the code to work when there is no www in the request or no http/https.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you need just redirect all to https and subfolder

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/wp/$1 [R=301,L]
```